# Deploy operation timeout

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I'm developing my back-end with service fabric and when I try to deploy the application at home I get:

> Copying application package to image store...
>
> Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage : Operation timed out.

But when I do this at work, I'm able to deploy it successfully. I imagine that it has to do with my routing at home or something, that makes the operation take too much time and time out.

Does anyone know where can I set the timeout threshold? As I see it, it should be set to  according to this:

[image: Settings]

Thanks!

Comment: The updated Service Fabric SDK version 2.3.301.9590 (dated 9/26) continues to have the same issue both in Visual Studio and PowerShell.  Any known workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the copy timeout is not currently configurable. This will be added in an upcoming release.

Comment: The next release of the SDK will offer this setting. It should be available in the next couple of weeks.